# IOS: How can pre-created objects find themselves?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, object, ios5, communication

I'm a complete beginner to IOS, so the question may be dumb, but I cannot to see the wood for the trees:

When I started a new project in XCode 4.2, two implementation files were pre-created, i.e. AppDelegate.m and ViewController.m.

As far as I understand it, they declare one class each, and when I run the application, the two respective objects AppDelegate and ViewController are pre-instantiated by the operating system for me.

Now I'm doing certain stuff in the AppDelegate and want to update a text label which is a property of the ViewController.

But I do not find a way to refer the ViewController object.

Normally, inside the ViewController, I can update the text label with 
`self.MyTextLabel = @"myText"`. But AppDelegate is "outside" and  did not instantiate ViewController, so there is no pointer available.

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's not clear without more information what your project structure looks like. Recent templates create view controllers in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but it could just as well be an outlet when loaded from a `MainWindow.xib` like old templates do. No way for us to point to something we cannot know about.

Comment: Hm, but is it wrong to assume that everyone with the newest XCode 4.2 would get the identical file and template structure when creating a new project? (In case I haven't mentionned it, this is an IOS application, single view project).

Comment: My Xcode 4.2 single view application generates the following line in the app delegate: `self.viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];`. That's the instantiation of view controller you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of an iOS app can be quite overwhelming, but let me assure you there's no magic going on here.

Your `main.m` usually contains a line like this:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

As soon as the app has started `-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions` in your `AppDelegate.m` will be called. Here you'll usually find the creation of your view controller. In your app delegate you can access the view controller through it's property it is retained in.

```
self.viewController.myTextLabel = @"myText";
```

However if `myTextLabel` is an outlet set in a XIB file, the property will only refer to an actual `UILabel` after the view for your controller has been loaded from the XIB. This usually happens as soon as you access the `.view` property yourself, or after you add your view controller to another view controller like a `UINavigationController`. (This however depends on the template you chose for your project).

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4.2 you can find the creation of the ViewController object in the method:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

you should see a line that looks like

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is the unchanged empty method: ` - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}`

Comment: Thats really interesting, do you have a MainWindow.xib file, or something along those lines?

Comment: There is no xib file, I have only a bunch of h and m files, one storyboard file, and other stuff like plist, pch, strings and so on.

Comment: Ok, then it is in your storyboard file, I'm unable to create a base storyboard project, but the idea between a xib and a storyboard is basically the same.  Long story short, the linkage between the two objects, your app delegate, and the view controller, is created in the storyboard file.  What this means is you can still access the viewcontroller in the delegate as `self.viewController.myTextLabel`  If that isn't the case, I can walk you through how to create that linkage yourself

Comment: I'm afraid it seems to be that way. Trying `self.ViewController.MyTextLabel = ..`  yields an error "Property ViewController not found on object of type AppDelegate *"

Comment: I'm really curious, can you open your storyboard file and post a screenshot of it?

Comment: You mean as source code? I just tried it, but after pasting here it says "-2400 characters left", so it's too big for this comment. Is there another way?

Comment: Assuming you're on mac, you can take a screenshot with cmd+shift+3 with your xcode window open, and then upload that into your question

Comment: I can't insert an image , I first need 10 repuations, but I have an external link to it [Screenshot](http://db.tt/9zyZoZP0)

Comment: Well there's your first problem, that shouldn't be viewed as an XML file, try right-clicking on the file in the browser at the left, and select Open As-> Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard